# set default value in option select dropdown which the user selected php

Tags: php

First let's assume that the user has selected an ID to edit the specific data.

[Here's where the user select to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUm78.jpg)

[Output will be here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLgg2.png)

But my problem is that it's not highlighting the specific data where the user need to edit and if the user save it the value will be 0 or null.

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtGRs.png)        [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PV2W.png)

I want to highlight the specific data where the user need to edit like this one..

[Hihglighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKgVT.png)

I have 2 queries:
Here's are all my query to get the subject , semester/term and schoolyear:

```
$sql1 = "select * from subject";
$subject = $conn -> query($sql1);

$sql2 = "select * from sy";
    $sy = $conn -> query($sql2);

$sql3 ="select * from term";
$semester = $conn -> query($sql3);
```

and here's my query to get the subject code and the subject description where the user select the id to edit..

```
$sql4 = "select subject.Subject_Description ,subject.Subject_Code, subject_offer.Subject_Offer_ID, term.Term_Name
                from subject_offer
                inner join subject on subject_offer.Subject_Code = subject.Subject_Code
                inner join term on subject_offer.Term_ID = term.Term_ID
                where subject_offer.Subject_Offer_ID = '$id'";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql4)->fetch_object();
```

Here's the code for my dropdown or option select..

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Subject</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <select class="form-control  form-control-md col-sm-12" id="inputSmall" name="subject">
                                        <option  disabled selected ><?php echo $result->Subject_Code . '' .$result->Subject_Description ?></option>
                                            <?php while($row1 = $subject->fetch_object() ):  ?>
                                            <option  value="<?php echo $row1->Subject_Code ?>" >
                                                <?php echo $row1->Subject_Code.' &nbsp;&nbsp; '.$row1->Subject_Description; ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Term_ID` in select clause of your second query. Also, you are missing value attribute in your disabled option. Should be:

```php
<option  disabled selected value="<?php echo $result->Subject_Code ?>">
    <?php echo $result->Subject_Code . '&nbsp;&nbsp;' .$result->Subject_Description ?>
</option>
```

I usually do it differently, that is, mark the selected option when its value is the current one:

```php
<select class="form-control  form-control-md col-sm-12" id="inputSmall" name="subject">
    <?php while($row1 = $subject->fetch_object() ):  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row1->Subject_Code ?>" <?= $row1->Subject_Code === $result->Subject_Code ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
            <?php echo $row1->Subject_Code.' &nbsp;&nbsp; '.$row1->Subject_Description; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: ohh I forgot.. and im so sorry for my very bad english.. but I have 3 queries.. 1 for the subject , 2 for the semester and , 3 for the term.. im going to edit sir my question.. im so sorry

Comment: Updated the answer. But I'm not sure if disabled option (if user won't change the selected value) will be send on POST.

Comment: The second example is not using the disabled option.

Comment: the $result is where I get the Subject_Code and it's Description where the user select the id , can I sent you a video sir? I uploaded this on youtube..